# Get images from documents directory to collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I get images from documents directory to poplulate a collection view. So far  I get all the images dumped into each cell according to my log, (or at least the image name is printed in the log)

First im getting the image names from the documents directory `filelist` is an NSMutable array of imageNames.png

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:nil];
    fileList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *filename in dirContents) {
        NSString *fileExt = [filename pathExtension];

        if ([fileExt isEqualToString:@"png"]) {

            [fileList addObject:filename];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"document folder content list %@ ",fileList);
```

This  returns a list of my png file names in my `NSMutsableArray` `fileList`. Then I want to get all these images into my collection view

```
//set up cell from nib in viewDidLoad
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.appliancesCollectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];


     /////


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


return fileList.count;
NSLog(@"collection view count is %@",fileList);

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Setup cell identifier
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSString *fileName = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: fileName]];
NSLog(@"cell Bg image %@",fileList);

return cell;

}


The probelm is nothing shows up in my collection view cells
```

Comment: what's the actual problem, though?  I notice you're returning the count from "`numberOfItemsInSection:`" correctly, except that you are trying to do a NSLog AFTER you've returned.

Comment: Nothing shows up in my cells, just the cell nib empty, nslog on count return gone, thanks

Comment: change "`NSLog(@"cell Bg image %@",fileList);`" to "`NSLog(@"cell Bg image %@",fileName);`" and are you seeing the correct expected filename?

Comment: yep expected file name is logged

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that contentsOfDirectoryAtPath returns relative file paths. And you need absolute. Something like following should be used:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:nil];
fileList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; // NEW LINE 1

for (NSString *filename in dirContents) {
    NSString *fileExt = [filename pathExtension];
    if ([fileExt isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]; // NEW LINE 2
        [fileList addObject:fullPath]; // NEW LINE 3
    }
}
NSLog(@"document folder content list %@ ",fileList);
```

Comment: what is `filename`? can you expand on this relative to my posted code

Comment: My 'filename' is the same as yours. Please look at new example. I have marked new/updated lines with comments // NEW LINE ...

Comment: Thanks for that, ok that does indeed supply the absoulute file path, thanks very much, im still not getting the background to change must be something else im missing.  Plus 1 for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [imageWithContentsOfFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile%3a) instead imageNamed:

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:<imageNameWithoutExtansion>ofType:<fileExtansion>];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filePath]];
```

Comment: still same issue, that code is for loading one singular image surley